# JqGrid & Adobe AIR : Grid doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, air

I'm developping an Adobe AIR application which gathers data (from intranet webservices) and stores it in AIR's SQLite database. I want to display this data using jqGrid, but the grid doesn't show up.

At the moment i'm using local data since I don't have access to the webservices yet. I created dummy records in the DB just to be able to make the GUI. The data recovery from the database works perfectly fine, but when i want to add rows to the grid, i get a "false" answer for every row. Here's my code :

```
$('#result-table').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'clientSide',
    colNames:['Id','Date', 'Code Projet','Login Utilisateur'],
    colModel :[ 
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55, sorttype:'int'}, 
    {name:'str_date',index:'str_date', width:90, sorttype:'date', datefmt:'dd/mm/yyyy'}, 
    {name:'code_projet',index:'code_projet', width:80, align:'right',sorttype:'text'}, 
    {name:'user_login',index:'user_login', width:80, align:'right',sorttype:'text'}],
    caption: 'Résultats de la recherche'
}); 

for(i=0;i<liste.data.length;i++)
{
    var p = liste.data[i];

    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(p.date);
    var str_date = date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear();
    var row = {id:p.id, date:str_date, codeprojet: p.code_projet, userlogin:p.user_login};
    var result = $('#result-table').addRowData(p.id, p);
}
```

`liste` represents the return of the DB. All the data is stored in `liste.data`. If you have any questions regarding the rest of the code,or need an explanation about this one, just comment this post, i'll edit it asap.

Thanks for help.
Regards from France ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write:

```
var result = $('#result-table').addRowData(p.id, row);
```

Also, for what its worth, some of your column names in the JavaScript object do not match up with the names in the colmodel:

- You said `str_date` in the colmodel but `date` in the object
- You declared `user_login` in the colmodel but say `userlogin` in the object

Comment: As for the column names, it doesn't matter, as long as the key from the arrow i insert matches the name from the colmodel. And for the addRowData, i'll check that